# Detecting duplicates while adding records to a SQL table

Tags: sql, join, duplicates, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I have a weird situation. I'm trying to add records to a SQL table recursively.

Table structure (simplified):

```
TableA
Key1  Key2 Description
```

Suppose I already update TableA with some records:

```
Key1   Key2  Description
12345  98765 Name1
23456  87654 Name2
34567  76543 Name3
45678  65432 Name4
```

I need to grab all records by Key2 now and look them up in another table (TableB), but I don't need to update TableA if the combination of Key1 and Key2 already exists.
So for example, if I find a record in TableB with Key2 = 87654 and Key1 = 15965, I should update TableA as follows:

```
Key1   Key2   Description
87654  15965  Name59
```

But if I find a record in TableB with Key2 = 87654 and Key1 = 23456, I **shouldn't** create record in TableA at all:

```
Key1  Key2  Description
87654 23456 Name59
```

The above record should **not** be created.

Here's my query:

```
insert into TableA
(key1, key2, Description)
select Key1, Key2, Description from TableB
join TableB TableB.Key1 = TableA.key2
and TableB.Key2 <> TableA.Key1
and not exists(select 1 from TableA where TableA.Key2= TableB.Key1and TableA.Key1 = TableB.Key2)
```

This actually inserts duplicates so at the end this is what I get:

```
Key1   Key2  Description
12345  98765 Name1
23456  87654 Name2
34567  76543 Name3
45678  65432 Name4
76543  74185 Name5
87654  82563 Name6
87654  23456 Name7
76543  34567 Name8
65432  45678 Name9
```

I'm trying to avoid inserting the last 3 records. 
Anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

edit: Just to clarify...here's my dataset:

```
Key1                                    Key2
E7483934-9AF7-E111-9912-78E7D16510D0    8FDE361D-B5C6-E011-A943-78E7D1644F78
E7483934-9AF7-E111-9912-78E7D16510D0    5001D99D-966B-E111-8FD2-78E7D16510D0
E7483934-9AF7-E111-9912-78E7D16510D0    76E8758E-A366-E111-B7C5-78E7D16510D0
E7483934-9AF7-E111-9912-78E7D16510D0    FB6F054F-E2BE-E511-9410-005056B5201F
E7483934-9AF7-E111-9912-78E7D16510D0    4A2007DA-E2BE-E511-9410-005056B5201F
E7483934-9AF7-E111-9912-78E7D16510D0    AE90299F-FAF5-E211-8706-D8D385B829F8
E7483934-9AF7-E111-9912-78E7D16510D0    76E9758E-A366-E111-B7C5-78E7D16510D0
E7483934-9AF7-E111-9912-78E7D16510D0    EB483934-9AF7-E111-9912-78E7D16510D0
8FDE361D-B5C6-E011-A943-78E7D1644F78    AE90299F-FAF5-E211-8706-D8D385B829F8
8FDE361D-B5C6-E011-A943-78E7D1644F78    EB483934-9AF7-E111-9912-78E7D16510D0
8FDE361D-B5C6-E011-A943-78E7D1644F78    76E9758E-A366-E111-B7C5-78E7D16510D0


AE90299F-FAF5-E211-8706-D8D385B829F8    8FDE361D-B5C6-E011-A943-78E7D1644F78
76E9758E-A366-E111-B7C5-78E7D16510D0    8FDE361D-B5C6-E011-A943-78E7D1644F78
EB483934-9AF7-E111-9912-78E7D16510D0    8FDE361D-B5C6-E011-A943-78E7D1644F78
```

So the top portion is TableB (my source table).
I need to look this table up by specific Key1 value (say WHERE TableB.key1 = 'E7483934-9AF7-E111-9912-78E7D16510D0'), pull the records with that value into another table (TableA), then again look up TableB but by TableB.key1 = TableA.key2 and if the records exist add them to TableA table. The caveat is I don't want TableA to have the same combination of key1+key2. So if you look at the above example, I only want the first 11 records pulled into TableA, but it also additionally pulls in the last 3 which I don't need because those combinations already exist in TableA.

```
TIA,
-Tony.
```

Comment: I think perhaps you are mixing up `key1` and `key2` in your question. In some parts of your question the values for `key1` and `key2` swap around. Was this intended?

Comment: So the intend was to first pull all records from TableB with specific key1 values into a temp-table (for example) TableA, then read TableA on key2 values, look them up in TableB again but by TableB.key1 = TableA.key2 and if found, add more records to TableA, but I need to exclude records where TableA exists on TableA.key1 = TableB.key2 and TableA.key2 = TableA.key1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditions in the `join` clause to not insert unwanted records.

```
insert into TableA
(key1, key2, Description)
select b.key1, b.key2, b.description 
from TableB b
join TableA a on (b.key1 <> a.key1 and b.key1 <> a.key2)
              or (b.key2 <> a.key1 and b.key2 <> a.key2)
```

Comment: Well, I need to join TableB on a specific criteria (TableB.key1 = TableA.key2)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use joins, or use them only to negate the records you want to insert.

When using joins, the database will fetch all records from TableB, compare with each record of TableA and if there's a single one that validates it, it'll pass. Following your example, the unwanted row could be validated by the first row of table A, for example (in your example you are even joining TableB with TableB... I assume the joined is TableA).

Not using the joins based on your query:

```
insert into TableA
(key1, key2, Description)
select Key1, Key2, Description from TableB as B
where not exists(select 1 from TableA as A where A.Key2=B.Key1 and A.Key1=B.Key2)
```

Or using joins to negate/block unwanted rows:

```
insert into TableA
(Key1, Key2, Description)
select distinct B.Key1, B.Key2, B.Description 
from TableB as B
left outer join TableA as A on A.Key2=B.Key1 and A.Key1=B.Key2
where A.Key1 is null
```

Considering that Key1 may not be null. Also use distinct to prevent records that match more than one row from being copied.